# do postback then re-direct to a page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, redirect, postback

I'm trying to do a javascript postback and then re-direct to a different page but it keeps posting back to the current page

Here's my code

```
$(this).prepend('<a class="booknow2 sidelink sidelinkNew" href="javascript:__doPostBack(\'SetSess\',\'\')"><img src="../../images1/button/leftEdge.png" width="4" height="35" style="float:left; margin:0; padding:0;" alt="book now" /><img src="../../images1/button/rightEdge.png" width="4" height="35" style="float:right; margin:0; padding:0;" alt="book now" /><span>Check availability &raquo;</span></a>');
```

And here's my `SetSess` postback command

```
Sub SetSess()

Session("TenHolStDateNewCheck") = "%"

response.redirect("searchresults/default.aspx")

End Sub
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the jquery ajax function to call a page which set the session and then re-directed

Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

__doPostBack the first parameter populates the __EVENTTARGET parameter...  I could be wrong, but I wasn't aware that it automatically invoked methods.  I think you have to do that yourself by doing in Load event:

```
if (request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] = "SetSess") Then
    SetSess()
End if
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a hidden button link so the page product the permission to accept this post back

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
         onclick="LinkButton1_Click" style="display:none;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then you can call your post back.

```
__doPostBack('<%=LinkButton1.ClientID%>','');
```

and your code be something like that.

```
$(this).prepend('<a class="booknow2 sidelink sidelinkNew" 
    href="javascript:__doPostBack(\'<%=LinkButton1.ClientID%>\',\'\')">
    <img src="../../images1/button/leftEdge.png" width="4" height="35" 
    style="float:left; margin:0; padding:0;" alt="book now" /><img src="../../images1/button/rightEdge.png" 
    width="4" height="35" style="float:right; margin:0; padding:0;" 
    alt="book now" /><span>Check availability &raquo;</span></a>');
```

... and the function on code behind

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Here the work and the redirect of you
}
```

Hope this work.

Comment: I seem to be getting a end of statement error when putting the protected void in?